# MessageXmlProtocolError Arguments: Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, basichttpbinding

I have a website which contains a small Silverlight plugin that calls a very simple WCF service to save values in Session.

It works fine on my PC and works ok only on my computer on the server (hosting provider). I noticed that for all machines that have Silverlight Developer Edition installed my Silverlight app works fine, however for all machines that have Silverlight Generic Edition installed my application fails when calling WCF service with the following message:
**Additional information: [MessageXmlProtocolError]
Arguments:
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the...**

I have crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml files in place which should be correct and I am using basicHttpBinding with no security. Also, there is no issues with developer editions. Can anyone help? (Silverlight version = 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added some code that changes wcf service url to make sure it runs on the correct server. This fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the response received is not what the WCF service was expecting. From the MSDN documentation, MessageXmlProtocolError is:

"A problem occurred with the XML that was received from the network. See the inner exception for more details."

This means that you need to see what the inner exception is in order to determine the actual cause.

If the WCF service is hosted in IIS on a specific URL, it could be that the senders are not authorized to access that URL in the web site. We've had this issue more than once.

Ways to help troubleshoot the problem include:

1) Install the SDK on a computer having the problems to see if you can get the full exception.

2) Use WCF tracing by adding a block like the following to your web.config (assuming the WCF service is hosted in IIS):

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="c:\log\WebTrace.svclog"  />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

3) Use a tool like fiddler to trace the request and response from the WCF client to see if you can track down the issue.

Comment: My problem is that if I install Silverlight SDK on the client machine then everything works. What code do I put into web.config for tracing? My other issue is that I cannot access server itself as I am using shared hosting environment.

Comment: Sorry about the web.config: I had the code in answer, but hadn't attributed it; it should be visible now.